# PHP Security - How does Facebook block login from other hosts?

Tags: security

I search alot about this topic but I didn't found any useful solutions.

How does Facebook detect that the host isn't Facebook even if the referrer and host can be faked in the request headers using curl or an HTML form in another website.

If you send the login POST parameters to https://m.facebook.com/login/ , Facebook will display a message : (For security reasons, don't login from website other than Facebook) and they block the login.

So how they can 100% sure that the request is made from Facebook.com?

Thank you.

Comment: Please show your code what you have tried and how you come to your conclusion.

Comment: I actually would upvote this question if you provide more information including examples. For now it is just an assertion without any illustration. Thus it is subject to get closed as offtopic.

Answer (score 0):

They probably use a version of CSRF. Looking at the actual login form, there are 14 (fourteen!) hidden HTML fields in addition to the username and password. At least 4 of them look to me like a CSRF token. You would need to pull them all out of the home page and send them in with your login request. Tools like curl can send such a complete request, but you will still need to retrieve all the fields yourself.

[CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) is a way of preventing (or at least making very very difficult) a website from being POSTed to from a page not on its own website. The usual way of implementing it is to create a one-time-use token, store it sever-side in the session and also put it on the web page. If the HTTP POST omits the token, then the POST is not accepted. Reload the page with the form and the token is re-generated. Some sites have an expiry for the token, too - that is, it will only work for a short time, such as 10 minutes.

BTW, this has nothing to do with PHP. CSRF support is in many many frameworks in many languages and it's not difficult to build it yourself.

Comment: This should not apply to a cURL request from a server. *"even if the referrer and host can be faked in the request headers using curl"*

Comment: If a curl request can create the exact same POST that a browser would from the homepage, including all form fields and all correct headers - and I know it can - then it should work.

Comment: You could add this to your answer. Further more FB might do an IP check and exclude pools known to be assigned to hosting/housing networks. This can improve security but not exclude unknown ranges.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
But in facet you can write a simple HTML form and save it on Desktop for example as .html file and open it, you can login normally!
This is the code: (`<form action="https://m.facebook.com/login/" method="post">
<input name="email"><br><br>
<input name="pass"><br><br>
<input type="submit"><br><br>
</form>`). 
This form will not work if you upload it to your website or put it in localhost server like XAMPP where the host IP is your own IP. 
So I think this is beyond CSRF.